# Set week_of_month back to current after having added 1 week before

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

Let's say I have this code:

```
String day = "12";
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int week_of_month = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
int day_of_week = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); //For example, today is Monday

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 07);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 05);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if (day.contains("1")){ //here I set calendar day to Monday
        calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, week_of_month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        if (day_of_week == Calendar.MONDAY) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
                //I add one week in case today is Monday but 07:05 was in the past
//THE PROBLEM IS CAUSED HERE..
            }
        }
  }

if (day.contains("2")){ //here I set calendar day to Tuesday

        **calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, week_of_month); //This seems not working for some reason**

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
            if (day_of_week == Calendar.TUESDAY) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
                //In the example, today is Monday so this code is not running
            }
        }
 }
```

The problem is that in the first if statement the calendar date is set correctly (even if System.currentTimeMillis() > calendar.getTimeInMillis()). However in the second if-statement, if I have added one week previously in the 1st-if-statement the calendar date is set for the Tuesday of the next week and not for the Tuesday of this week.

Comment: Couldn't you create a new instance of `Calendar`?

Comment: @JediBurrell I've thought about doing it, but I firstly want to know if it can be done this way..

Comment: can't get you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time in milliseconds to the System's current time.

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```